# Memory Leak in ReportViewer but how do i access the ReportPanel?

Tags: c#, winforms, report, rdlc

[image: Profiler screen]

I am trying to hunt down this event handler (leak) but cannot for the life of me find where the ReportPanel is.  No help on Microsoft either...

The crux question is, how do I null out the ContextMenuStrip property to sever the link to the window?  I assume this is an internal class, I don't create any extra controls.

UPDATE:
[image]

Comment: This is probably internal class. To access it you will have to decompile dll.

Comment: Have you tried to [disable it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.winforms.reportviewer.showcontextmenu.aspx)?

Comment: Disable what? How would help?

Comment: There are 3 properties in ReportViewer ContextMenuStrip, ContextMenu and ShowContextMenu. Try to play around with those. Disabling/setting to null might sever the link.

Comment: I realize that this is almost 2-years old. . . but just wondering if you ever found a solution? I'm seeing the same type of leak.

Comment: I updated my question with my clean up code.  hope it helps you.